# How to figure out the width of a string dynamically in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let's say I have a text called: `This`. I want to figure out the width of the text called `This` so that I can assign a width to another view's frame. How do I go about it?

```
struct BadgeTextView: View {

var text: String

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(3)
        .frame(width: text.???, height: <#T##CGFloat?#>, alignment: <#T##Alignment#>)

}
}
```

Comment: "Width" is not an intrinsic property of a string. Figuring out the width of a string requires a font and a font size. Just make sure you consider that as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This extension to `String` should build on Sweeper's suggestion to let you get the width of a `String` **given a certain font**:

```swift
extension String {
   func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.width
    }
}
```

This would be used like so: `let width = "SomeString".widthOfString(usingFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold))`

Comment: That is so brilliant! I was messing with GeometryReady and preference(key:value:) without success.

Comment: I am using Courier because it is monospaced.  The width of a string with "1" repeated 36 times is 257.34375, while a string with 36 "M"s is 492.1875.  Because it is monospaced, shouldn't these widths be identical?